# Nodejs Cannot Read Property When Running in Docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, neo4j

I'm trying to run the example Neo4j Node project in Docker containers but I'm having an issue with the Node part. The project runs fine locally but when I run it in a docker container I get this error:

```
const neo4j = window.neo4j;
              ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I have pretty much no JavaScript / Node experience so just looking for any help to point me in the right direciton.

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
COPY package-lock.json /app
RUN npm config set strict-ssl false
RUN npm cache clean --force && npm install && npm install -g serve
#RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build
COPY serve.json dist/serve.json

CMD ["node", "src/app.js"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

The demo project is: https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-javascript-bolt

UPDATE
The comment from Amir seems to have solved the original issue. This was to change

```
const neo4j = window.neo4j;
```

to

```
const neo4j = require("neo4j-driver");
```

with neo4j-driver being the name of the module.

Now I'm getting this similar issue if anyone has any ideas:

```
$(function () {
^

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Comment: window object is a part of browser API. This isn't available in NodeJs environment

Comment: You need to do 
const neo4j = require("neo4j");

Comment: Thanks. I had to change it to be require("neo4j-driver"), which is the name of the module, but it seems to have done something now. Getting a similar issue now which I'll update the questions with.

Comment: again `$` is a Jquery API which runs in browser. Not available in NodeJS environment. You are looking at a wrong documentation.

Comment: I'm not looking at any specific documentation. As I said I'm just trying to run the example project, which I linked, in a Docker container. Is there a different approach I need to take, or is it not possible with that project?

Comment: Can you please share the link to project?

Comment: @user3193861
You might need to serve the output of the build. In the dockerfile you had shared, you are serving the source file itself. Can you try updating to something like this?

`CMD ["node", "build/app.js"]`